# Apache issues with permission on mac 10.10

Tags: macos, apache, osx-yosemite

having trouble getting apache to access `/Users/username/Documents` for a PHP project.

**`httpd.conf`**

```
User admin
Group staff
```

**`username.conf`**

```
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
Require all granted
```

**`Folder permission`**

```
drwxr-xr-x /Users
drwxr-xr-x+ /Users/kristiannissen
drwx------+ /Users/kristiannissen/Documents
```

when I access my project URL I get this in the apache error log

```
[Thu Oct 23 21:25:58.528515 2014] [core:error] [pid 1887] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:52157] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/Users/kristiannissen/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Thu Oct 23 21:27:45.287472 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1882] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I followed the guide from http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/ for some of this, but it's still not working.

It was working perfectly before upgrading to os 10.10, now localhost no longer shows "It works" from apache anymore.

Comment: Check if the filesystem permissions have changed for `/Users/kristiannissen/Documents/` after the upgrade.

Comment: @kums how do I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the link.  do you have the file `/etc/apache2/users/kristiannissen.conf` ?

and does that file contain

```
<Directory "/Users/kristiannissen/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` there is this section

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Which blocks access to everything on /  you  need to specifically allow what you want.   And since it it apache 2.4, you need to use the Require syntax as opposed to the Allow syntax, but adding the kristiannissen.conf  file as indicated above and restarting apache should fix it.

Comment: I made these changes but the same error, no difference

Comment: logs show the same thing. What are the perms on your dirs all the way Down the path.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x /Users, drwxr-xr-x+ /Users/kristiannissen, drwx------+ /Users/kristiannissen/Documents

Comment: Documents has perms 700 which mean only the owner (you) can read it.  The webserver runs as user Admin/Staff.  You can either chmod 750 Documents,assuming you are in staff group, that would give the webserver access to the directory.  Or you can move your docroot to a different directory and give that dir 755 perms. so you don't let everybody with access to your computer access to your documents directory

Comment: works as expected, after taking the Sites folder into use, it's working

Answer (score 0):

For those of you getting a `Forbidden` (403) error with *json* AJAX requests, for example in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'json',
    // ...
});
```

In your **username.conf** file for apache in:

```
# replace 'username' with your actual username
/private/etc/apache2/users/username.conf
```

If you have:

```
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Require all denied
</LimitExcept>
```

Change it to:

```
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Require all granted
</LimitExcept>
```

This worked for me, hope it helps.